# perl, read blocking using IO::Select and IO::Socket::INET

Tags: perl, sockets, unix, nonblocking

This server works fine but if I do this

> bash$ (echo -n "abcd" ;sleep 50 ; echo "efgh") | nc localhost 9090

The server blocks for 50 seconds.In my complete code I have more than one `IO::Select::INET`. I have another socket listen other port (1234), and I can't process anything in that port while the server is blocking by the sleep. I try change the `getline` by `getc` but I only read the first letter "a" and it blocks.

Someone can help me?

```
use common::sense;
use IO::Select;
use IO::Socket;

use constant PORT1 => 9090;
use constant TIMEOUT => 1;

my $event_socket  = new IO::Socket::INET(Listen => 1, LocalPort => PORT1, ReuseAddr => 1) 
    or die "Can't bind event_socket: $@\n";

my $sel = IO::Select->new;
$sel->add($event_socket);

my $event_emiter = undef;

while(1){ 
    foreach my $sock (my @ready = $sel->can_read(TIMEOUT)) {
        if ($sock == $event_socket) {
            my $new = $event_socket->accept;
            binmode($new, ":encoding(UTF-8)");
            $sel->add($new);

            $event_emiter=$new;

            warn "[event socket] connect from ",$new->peerhost, "\n";
        } elsif ($sock == $event_emiter) {
            unless($sock->eof){
                my $recv_data = $sock->getline;
                warn "[event socket] LOL '$recv_data'\n";
            } else {
                $sel->remove($sock);
                $sock->close;
                $event_emiter = undef;
                warn "[socket] disconnect\n";
            }
        } else {

            $sel->remove($sock);
            $sock->close;

            warn "[socket] disconnect\n";
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14188768/589924)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than reading available data, you're reading until you read a newline. Always use `sysread`.

Change

```
    elsif ($sock == $event_emiter) {
        unless($sock->eof){
            my $recv_data = $sock->getline;
            warn "[event socket] LOL '$recv_data'\n";
        } else {
            $sel->remove($sock);
            $sock->close;
            $event_emiter = undef;
            warn "[socket] disconnect\n";
        }
    }
```

to

```
    elsif ($sock == $event_emiter) {
        our $buf; local *buf = \$bufs{$fh};  # alias $buf = $bufs{$fh};

        my $rv = sysread($fh, $buf, 64*1024, length($buf));
        if (!$rv) {
            if (defined($rv)) {  # EOF
                # ... Handle anything left in $buf ...
            } else {  # Error
                # ... Handle error ...
            }

            delete $bufs{$fh};
            $sel->remove($sock);
            $sock->close;
            $event_emiter = undef;
            warn "[socket] disconnect\n";
            next;
        }

        while ($buf =~ s/^(.*)\n//) {
            warn "[event socket] LOL '$1'\n";
        }
    }
```

And add `my %bufs;` outside the select loop.

Comment: ok... I'm trying to avoid sysread (in fact, avoid deal with buffer). But if there is no other way... my fear is pick some line in the middle and add some complex way to add the buffer to the next step of this loop.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Just replace `eof` and `getline` with what I posted. `warn "[event socket] LOL '$recv_data'\n";` is `process_message("$1")` in my code.

Comment: Yes, but in case of "line1\r\nline2\r\nline3\r\n" there is a possibility of capture "line1\r\nlin" in my buffer (in case of large line, etc). I need to save the last "lin to concatenate to the next buffer. but it is not a big problem. Thanks again.

Comment: It's possible to get that in a single read, but my code already handles that. Go read my code again. (Btw, I just updated my answer to show how to integrate my code with yours.)

Answer (score 0):

It blocks here:

```
my $recv_data = $sock->getline;
```

This is because getline() is blocking call which waits for `\n`. Instead, you should `sysread()` and assemble your command in separate buffer.